# Having Lambdas subscribe to multiple Kinesis Delivery Streams in AWS Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kinesis

Would it be something like this to subscribe to two streams? I added another event underneath.

```
Resources:
    LambdaFunction:
        Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
        Properties:
          Handler: lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.8
          CodeUri: .
          Events:
            Stream:
              Type: Kinesis
              Properties:
                Name: !Sub ${Environment}-stream1
                ShardCount: 1  
            Stream:
              Type: Kinesis
              Properties:
                Name: !Sub ${Environment}-stream2
                ShardCount: 1
```

Comment: Try and see how it works? If not, make new question with any error messages you get.